# What makes a village a "Hidden Village"?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto, there seem to be villages that are "Hidden Villages" such as Konohagakure no Sato and villages that are not "Hidden Villages" such as Tsuchigumo Village or Tonika Village. What makes a village a "Hidden Village"? Is it that they are run by a Kage, or is there some other reason?

Comment: hidden villages are villages that are hidden

Comment: No. Read the answer from here: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/825/why-are-hidden-villages-called-such/834#834. I want to know what distinguishes a village such as Konohagakure no Sato from a village such as Tonika Village.

Comment: @kuwaly your answer is also present in that question.

Comment: Not really. That question gives a more literal translation while I want to know what the actual difference is in-show (i.e. why Konoha got that specification while other villages didn't).

Answer (score 4):

It is stated on [this wiki page](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_geography), that

> Hidden Villages are parts of countries in which the country's ninja reside. Their leaders stand equally with the landlords ruling the countries they are a part of. A Hidden Village maintains its economy by training its citizens to be ninja from a young age and using them as manpower in various missions others would be willing to pay for, from weeding a garden for a single payment to receiving a constant budget from the country it resides in for being soldiers in case the country is involved in a war.

However, the same page lists Tsuchigumo Village and Tonika Village in the list of "hidden villages".

I would speculate that the largest ninja village in the country, the one directly responsible for it's defense, would be called a "hidden village" (i.e. have "village hidden in the " in the name), and the other smaller ones would probably be just "villages", even if they belong to a ninja clan or something.